# How do I extend all elements of a list to another list every Nth item

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to find a way to insert all elements from a list every nth element of another. There are several post similar but they are for single elements of a list to another list. What I am trying to figure out is taking the following list:

```
l1 = ["a","b"]
l2 = ["j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t"u"]
```

And outputting them together:

```
["j","k","l","a","b","m","n","o","a","b","p","q","r","a","b","s","t","u"]
```

What I'm thinking would work is something that at least starts with:

```
for x in 1st:
    for i in range(len(l2)):
        2nd.extend(l1)
```

I know this doesn't work but I'm not sure how to implement this.

In the specific output above, the first list is added after every 3rd element. It doesn't have to be every third element but I'm just using that as an example.

Can someone educate me on how to do this?

**EDIT:**
With the help of @Chris, I was able to find a 3rd party library called `more_itertools` and created a new code that does exactly what I was looking for. Here is what I came up with:

```
import more_itertools as mit

l1 = ["a","b"]
l2 = ["j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u"]

#We will place the elements of 1st after every two elements of 2nd 
l3 = list(mit.collapse(mit.intersperse(l1, l2, n=len(l1))))
```

Results:

```
>>> print(l3)
['j', 'k', 'a', 'b', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'n', 'o', 'a', 'b', 'p', 'q', 'a', 
'b', 'r', 's', 'a', 'b', 't', 'u']
```

I found that the `intersperse` function will allow the user to place an element into a separate list at the "nth" interval. In this example, I place the list of l1 in the l2 list after every second element (since len(l1) is equal to 2). The `collapse` function will take the list that was placed in l2 and put each element in order as a separate element.

Thank you to everyone that helped me with this. I enjoyed learning something new.

Comment: what happens if there is a "v" at the end of `2nd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy has the ability to split a list into evenly distributed smaller lists.  You can specify in `np.array_split` the list itself, adn the number of splits.  Here I used math.floor to get the even number of times the `n` value goes into the length of the list.  In this case you have `n=3` and the list has 12 elements, so it will return 4 as the number of resulting sublists.

The `[np.append(x,l1) for x....` part says to attach the values in l1 to the end of each sublist.  and `chain_from_iterable` will mash all of them together, and you can render that as a list with `list()`.

It has the side effect of adding the `l1` values at the very end as well, which if you don't want to you can use slicing to drop of the last `n` values where `n` is the length of the `l1` list.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import math

n = 3
l1 = ["a","b"]
l2 = ["j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u"]
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([np.append(x, l1) for x in np.array_split(l2,math.floor(len(l2)) / n)]))
```

or if you don't want to trailing append:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([np.append(x, 
                                              l1) for x in np.array_split(l2,
                                                                          math.floor(len(l2)) / n)]))[:-len(l1)]
```

Comment: Oops :)  Good catch

Comment: @HeapOverflow You probably got it right the first time

Comment: Thanks Chris, this worked. I am curious on how it works though?

Comment: @Hellyeah added some explanation

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I really appreciate it! You are the best.

Comment: I found another way to do what you showed me using 3rd part library `more_itertools`. Using your code I wrote it: `list(more_itertools.collapse(more_itertools.intersperse(l1, l2, n=len(l2))))` If you didnt lead me to this I probably would not have figured out about `more_itertools` Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Excellent follow up! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through every n'th element of list b and insert every iteration of list a.

```
    a = ["a", "b"]
    b = ["j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u"]
    
    n = 3  # where you want to insert
    
    while n < len(b):
        for i in range(len(a)):
            b.insert(n, a[i])
            n += 1  # increment n by 1 so 'b' insert after 'a'
        n += 3  # increment n by 3 every iteration to insert list a
    
    print(b)
```

Result: ['j', 'k', 'l', 'a', 'b', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'a', 'b', 'p', 'q', 'r', 'a', 'b', 's', 't', 'u']

Answer (score 1):

```
list3 = []
n = 3

for x in range(1, len(list2)+1):
    if x%n == 0 and x != len(list2):
        list3.append(list2[x-1])
        for y in list1:
            list3.append(y)
    else:
        list3.append(list2[x-1])

print(list3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1= ["a","b"]
list= ["j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u"]
d=[]
for i in list:
    print(list.index(i))
    if ((list.index(i)+1)%3==0 and list.index(i)!=0):
        d.append(i)
        d.extend(list1)

    else:
        d.append(i)
print(d)
```

Comment: Thanks for the lead Andy but this will add the first list after the sixth element of the second bu it will skip the next six elements.

Comment: Can you please check it , I have got output as 
["j","k","l","a","b","m","n","o","a","b","p","q","r","a","b","s","t","u"] is this not your are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

```
one = ["a","b"]
two = ["j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u"]

start =0
end = 3 #or whatever number you require
complete_list=[]
iterations = int(len(two)/3)
for x in range(iterations):
    sub_list= two[start:end]   
    start = start+3
    end= end+3
    complete_list.append(sub_list)
    if x < iterations-1:
        complete_list.append(one)
complete_list = flatten(complete_list)
```

There may be a shorter version of code to do this, but this will work as well.